# Cocoapods making Xcode go crazy?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I have one project that uses cocoapods, and whenever it's open Xcode goes crazy and my processing skyrockets on activities like ReflectionService. It seems like it is endlessly indexing the project or something, and it really kills my performance/battery life. No problem on non-cocoapod workspaces. Is this common, and if not, how can I fix this? I'm considering dropping cocoapods entirely over it.

Comment: Probably need a more specific example to get a good answer.  CocoaPod workspaces typically work fine.

Comment: How can I do that? Certainly can't post my entire project.